# Lack of shared methods and properties in windows form classes for specific forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I had noticed when building a vb.net app for the 100th time, that the class that VS.NET (Visual Studio) automatically generates for a specific windows form doesn't have shared anything. How does it function without any instances of it being created?

Comment: An instance *does* get generated, but it is carefully hidden in a VB.NET project.  You actually can see it, click the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer window, open the My Project node, open Application.myapp and double click Application.Designer.vb.  You'll see the OnCreateMainForm() method.  Understanding it is not so easy, this was hidden for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio writes to the class it generates as you keep on designing. You added a control - VS writes to the designer class. But the form class itself,

```
public class MyForm
    Inherits Form
```

is just like any other instance class. You probably have `Sub Main` somewhere and in it you have

```
Application.Run(New MyForm1())
```

So, it is not shared. Your form just another instance at runtime. You can declare your controls `public, private, friend`, to expose or not to expose to other clients. for example, you may want to expose control's text but not the whole control - do this

```
private txtInfo As TextBox

Public Property Info As String
    Get
        Return txtInfo.Text
    End Get
    Set (value as String)
        txtInfo.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```